# OpenCV how to create a DescriptorExtractor object

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am using OpenCV C++ library but I don't manage to create a `DescriptorExtractor` object.
Here is what I did :

```
Mat img = imread("testOrb.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
std::vector<KeyPoint> kp;
cv::Ptr<cv::ORB> detector = cv::ORB::create();
detector->detect( img, kp )
//this part works    

DescriptorExtractor descriptorExtractor;    
Mat descriptors;
descriptorExtractor.compute(img, kp, descriptors);
//when these 3 lines are added, an error is thrown
```

But I have the following error message :

```
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented () in detectAndCompute, file ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DescriptorExtractor` is an *abstract* class, so you can't instantiate it. It's just a common interface for descriptor extractors. You can do like:

```
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> descriptorExtractor = ORB::create();
Mat descriptors;
descriptorExtractor->compute(img, kp, descriptors);
```

Note that exists also `FeatureDetector`, that is the common interface for detecting keypoints, so you can do:

```
std::vector<KeyPoint> kp;
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = ORB::create();
detector->detect(img, kp);
```